Sending test events using curl to gcp subscription got 502 error
when I use curl to push test events to two of my subscriptions in GCP in one single environment, I got two different results:
curl -k https://loansettlement-[servername]-ts.a.run.app -H "X-Serverless-Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"
"This one works fine"

curl -k https://loanapplication-[servername]-ts.a.run.app -H "X-Serverless-Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"
curl: (56) CONNECT tunnel failed, response 502

I copied the url from GCP subscription so there shouldn't have been any spelling issue and I have checked the related subscription in GCP it is showing status active.
I have googled this error message and most answers suggest it is due to proxy error but since the other subscription works fine without any issue I really doubt it is due to proxy.
Is there anything I can do to resolve this?

To identify the root cause of the curl: (56) CONNECT tunnel failed, response 502 error you need to debuig what is happening behind the scene.
The issue could stem from service configuration, network issues, or permission problems. But have you tried to use verbose mode in the curl
curl -k -v https://loanapplication-[servername]-ts.a.run.app -H "X-Serverless-Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"

So you can look for DNS resolution errors, TLS Handshake and also have a better vision of the HTTP request/response headers.

Thank you for the comment. I tried to use the -v version. Aside from all the passing info. I got this: > Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

< HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway . What might be the cause?

I think you should think more abouth the network and firewall aspect of this issue The 502 Bad Gateway error indicates that the server received an invalid response from an inbound server so maybe you should debug the cloud run logs
gcloud logging read "resource.type=cloud_run_revision AND resource.labels.service_name=loanapplication-[servername]-ts"

Also you should validate the configuration and check the diffrences in the firewall maybe
gcloud compute firewall-rules list --filter="network:[NETWORK_NAME]"
gcloud run services describe loanapplication-[servername]-ts --region [REGION]
